# Manifest File for An Air App On Android

Tags: android, air, android-manifest, android-service

Is it possible to declare a service in the Air Manifest xml?

And if so, how?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have access to the full manifest in adobe AIR.
Go to NAMEOFYOURAPP-app.xml

After :

```
<!--The suppression of android.permission.INTERNET will prevent you from debugging.-->
                <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

You can add permissions

After :

```
    <![CDATA[
        <manifest android:installLocation="auto">
```

You can add activities and services.